# ActionScript 3: How to save binary data to files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

im doing a level editor for my game and i need to save the tilemap data (120x120 uint array) and character data (character type, position, rotation, stats, etc) to a .bin file. How can i do it? I know i can do it by using XMLs but it is not good for saving tilemaps... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `FileReference` class's save function. See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

This only works in Flash Player 10+, and requires user interaction. (It'll pop up a save dialog box) These restrictions are there for security reasons, if you want to be able to save flies directly (without user interaction), you'll have to use AIR, see the `FileStream` class ref for that: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

To save native Flash objects to an external file and load them in again, you'll need to write the data to a `ByteArray` first. `ByteArray` has two methods (writeObject & readObject) that make this trivial. see here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web based game, to be run in a web browser, and you want to save the data on the users system (not on a web server), I can think of two options:

If it is OK to require Flash Player 10, you can save and load data to and from local files on the users request, such as a button click, (not arbitrary from anywhere in your code) and via a standard file dialog. See [FileReference.save()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29).

You can also store data in a local [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). The data can be read and written without user interaction or a file dialog. Flash Player then serializes the data for you, but I think you should be able to save the kind of data you describe that way.